# Bash alias or function to create multiline file

Tags: bash, alias, eol

I have the following bash command that creates a multiline file in the current directory:

```
cat > data.txt <<EOL
Line 1
Another line
Something else
EOL
```

I'm trying to create a bash alias or function to run this command. I've tried the following but nothing happens:

```
alias create-file="
cat > ~/Desktop/stuffs/data.txt <<EOL
Line 1
Hello world
Another line
EOL"
```

No luck trying the funciton either:

```
function npmrcpersonal() {
  "cat > ~/Desktop/stuffs/data.txt <<EOL
  Line 1
  Hello world
  Another line
  EOL"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Using a function for your here-doc is recommended than an alias which does not work in non-interactive shells

Comment: Use a script instead of an alias or function; there are fewer problems of interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't quote the body of a function. And the here-doc shouldn't be indented.

```
function npmrcpersonal() {
  cat > ~/Desktop/stuffs/data.txt <<EOL
Line 1
Hello world
Another line
EOL
}
```

The `EOL` marker will only be recognized if it's at the left margin (unless you use `<<-EOL`, then it's allowed to be indented, but only with `TAB` characters, not spaces). The rest of the here-doc shouldn't be indented because those spaces will go into the file, and you probably don't want that.

Comment: Looks great. No way to use an alias here?

Comment: I advise you to just forget that aliases exist. They shouldn't be used except for the simplest substitutions.